# The activeCount(session) is not reducing in the Tivoli Performance viewer

Tags: performance, session-timeout, websphere-7, tivoli

We have an application with JSF (Icefaces) MVC and Spring service layer. Even on session invalidation the active count is not reducing in the Servlet Session Module of the Tivoli Performance viewer.

We have tried all the possibe session invalidation methodologies like below
1)httpsession.invalidate();
2)httpsession.setMaxInterval(0);
3)Removed all session attributes before invalidation
and by deleting the cookies during logout programatically in the code.

The definition of Active Count is Session is active if Websphere is processing a request that uses a session. But even after the session is invalidated in the code,Active count is not getting reduced in TPV.
We are able to see that the CreateCount and InvalidateCount are getting updated and are equal. We assume that this mean what ever session which got created are getting invalidated.
Please correct us if our understanding is incorrect.
But even after session invalidation the active count doesn't decrease.

Answer (score 0):

If InvalidateCount=CreateCount, then ActiveCount should indeed be zero. This sounds like a bug in Websphere that you should report to IBM support.